# Joomla! Undefined! Method! Error! Goes! Away! On! Refresh!

Tags: joomla

Fatal error: Call to undefined method CRM_Core_BAO_SchemaHandler::getMissingIndices() in /home/reports/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check/Component/Schema.php on line 40

This error appears after logging in and navigating to CiviCRM. Upon refreshing, this error disappears, and Civi works as normal. Clearing the Civi cache makes it appear again, before refreshing the screen again fixes it.

What could be causing this, and how can we solve it?

I thought file perms, but those all look ok.

JohnFF

Comment: That is a lot of exclamation marks JohnFF....

Comment: Tribute to The Register which does the same thing with headlines involving Yahoo!

Comment: Love the title. I think anyone silly enough to put an exclamation point in their name deserves a little teasing.

Comment: Voting this Q up - best title ever!

Comment: I always sound surprised by accident any time I read it.

"Well, your options are Drupal, WordPress, or Joomla!"

Comment: What civi version, what joomla version?